# GraphQL (Apollo): Can you access directives within resolve function?

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js, apollo-server

I'd like to make every field private, unless otherwise notated with a directive. Is it possible to get this information within a resolve function?

```
const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @public on FIELD_DEFINITION

  type Query {
    viewer: User @public
    secret: String
  }

  type User {
    id: ID!
  }
`

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

addSchemaLevelResolveFunction(schema, (parent, args, params, info) => {
  // Not possible
  if (info.fieldName.directive === 'public') {
    return parent;
  }

  throw new Error('Authentication required...');
});

const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });
```

Answer (score 4):

While there is a `directives` property on `FieldNode` object in the `fieldNodes` array, as far as I'm aware it's not populated with the directives that apply to that specific field.

Directives aren't really meant to be used as a flag for something that can be referenced in a resolver (schema level or otherwise). You may consider moving your logic inside the directive's `visitFieldDefinition` function:

```
const { defaultFieldResolver } = require('graphql')
const { SchemaDirectiveVisitor } = require('graphql-tools')

class PublicDirective extends SchemaDirectiveVisitor {
  visitFieldDefinition(field) {
    const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = field
    field.resolve = async function (source, args, context, info) {
      if (someCondition) {
        throw new SomeError()
      }
      return resolve.apply(this, [source, args, context, info])
    }
  }
}

const schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  schemaResolvers: {
    public: PublicDirective,
  },
})
```

Comment: Yeah, that works for something like a ``@private`` directive (public by default), but was hoping to find a way for the inverse.

Comment: Is there an easy way to automatically add directives to all fields (i.e. @private) at compilation time?

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't fully get what you were trying to do. You can have the directive inject some arbitrary property into the context, then check for that property's existence inside `addSchemaLevelResolveFunction`